# How many Batchables/Queables can be Queued in a Specific moment in Salesforce

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I would like to know if someone knows how many Batchables/Queables/Future.. (Apex Jobs) can have in a specific moment queued without obtain error when I'm queuing that jobs.

I have read in next link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm that the maximum execution of Apex Jobs is 250000 per 24 hours (depending also on how many licenses you have in the ORG), but my question is focus in how many can you have queued of course with different Scheduled Dates

Comment: I recommend you read [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166544/2212) to a related question that also comes into play that may be much more important and of relevance to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `@future`s and `Queueable` there is no concurrent limit, for `Batch` jobs there can be 100 queued `Batch` jobs in the flex queue.

However, there are limits on how many `Queueable` you can queue from a single thread. That limit is 50, or 1 if the current execution is already happening within a `Queuable`.

See [Queueable Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)

For `@future` you can queue 50 calls from a single thread. And futures cannot call other futures. Also, if you have more than 2000 futures in the queue, you will get performance penalties such that futures from other orgs will be processed first.

See [Future Apex documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm)